# What's the English equivalent of "闺蜜"

Tags: word-requests

闺蜜 in Chinese means two girls have very good relationship, and much closer than normal good friends but they are not lesbians.

The best I can get is the term *intimate relationship*, but it could be used to describe lesbians. Any other good suggestions?

Comment: Some geographical areas will use the term “girlfriends” for two females in a very good non romantic relationship. Shouldn’t this question be asked at English SE? You’ll get much better answers there.

Comment: Good idea, I will ask there too. Maybe, the person who know the word deeply could have a good answer. That's why I asked here.

Comment: "Bosom friends" is a common, though somewhat archaic term, though this term can be used for men too (and was quite common in Victorian novels to describe such).

Comment: @dan cross-posting is against SE's policies, it's likely that your ELL post will get closed seeing as this was posted 6 hours earlier.

Comment: @RobertColumbia that seems to be the consensus of native speakers. Thanks!

Comment: This is about English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferred translation:

**Bestie**

*New Century English-Chinese Dictionary*

Defines **Bestie** as:

> 挚友；好哥们儿；闺蜜；死党

**[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bestie)** #1 def:

> A person who means the world to you. The person that when you met you just kinda connected. The person that you were always there for. The person that isn't a love partner but they hold a special place in your heart. Someone that when they get hurt it hurts you too. Someone who no matter what happens between you two everything always ends up being alright. A person you can trust with anything.
>
> Richie is her bestie. She is his bestie. They are forever besties no matter what.

and definition #2

> An adoring nickname for one you hold in highest esteem, more commonly known as a best friend. A bestie is the person who you not only go shopping with on a regular basis but also trust implicitly with anything.. besties do not come and go like waves and sandcastles, they are more like permanent marker on American Eagle jeans, they'll stay with you forever. It is much better to have one pure andgood bestie who is true to you then multiple 'besties' (even though if theres more than one t usually will not count as a bestie, technically) who are only like pants that stay with you only until you get too fat for them, or you tear them (like hurting them, and then them being all unforgiving), or just until they fade. A true bestie would stick with you through all of it, walking in when the world walks out.
>
> Boyfriend: Hey, wanna go to the movies with me later?
>
> You: Oh my gosh I'm sorry maybe tomorrow I've got plans with my bestie already. I would never blow her off!

---

An alternative:

[Bosom Buddy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bosom_buddy)

> Noun
>
> bosom buddy (plural bosom buddies)
>
> A very close friend.

Comment: 闺蜜 in Chinese only applies for girls. Besties can be used for both men an women. It's like saying they are best friends. 闺蜜 is kinda like almost lesbians. :)